# Not able to replace all occurence of a json key correctly

Tags: javascript, json

Hi I have a nested json object.

I want to rename all occurrences of `total_exec_qty_buy` & `total_exec_qty_sell` to `total_exec_qty`; `total_num_ords_buy` & `total_num_ords_sell` to `total_num_ords`

I'm doing it in the following way:

```
newArray = JSON.stringify(newArray).split('"total_exec_qty_buy":').join('"total_exec_qty":');
```

When I do just one statement(above one) then the output is fine.
But when I do this:

```
newArray = JSON.stringify(newArray).split('"total_exec_qty_buy":').join('"total_exec_qty":');
     newArray = JSON.stringify(newArray).split('"total_exec_qty_sell":').join('"total_exec_qty":');
newArray = JSON.stringify(newArray).split('"total_num_ords_buy":').join('"total_num_ords":');
    newArray = JSON.stringify(newArray).split('"total_num_ords_sell":').join('"total_num_ords":');
```

then I get this output:

```
"\"\\\"[{\\\\\\\"total_wt_arr_slp_buy\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"-1.9322\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"total_exec_qty\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"49654\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"total_wt_buy\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"0.31\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"total_wt_arr_last_slp_buy\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"-0.1924\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"total_wt_ivwap_slp_buy\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"-0.1103\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"total_exec_val_buy\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"3224372.00\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"total_ord_qty_buy\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"61688\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"total_num_ords_buy\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"859\\\\\\\"},{\\\\\\\"total_wt_arr_last_slp_sell\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"-1.2509\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"total_ord_qty_sell\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"139654\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"total_exec_qty_sell\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"111012\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"total_wt_ivwap_slp_sell\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"-0.1833\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"total_wt_sell\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"0.69\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"total_exec_val_sell\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"7129344.00\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"total_num_ords_sell\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"1099\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"total_wt_arr_slp_sell\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"-2.4978\\\\\\\"},{\\\\\\\"total_wt_arr_last_slp\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"-0.9213\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"total_exec_qty\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"160666\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"total_wt_ivwap_slp\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"-0.1606\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"total_wt_arr_slp\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"-2.3216\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"total_ord_qty\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"201342\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"total_num_ords\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"1958\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"total_notional\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"10353698.63\\\\\\\"}]\\\"\""
```

Why is this happening??

Comment: I guess it's because you keep needlessly stringifying `newArray`, although it's already a string after the first operation.

Comment: You keep stringifying the array, which will each time escape the quotes for you. Try using a regex if you really want to fix this structure with string replacements, but it's probably easier if you'd just work with the object itsself and add/remove keys or just build up a new object with the correct keys. If you do want to keep using JSON.stringify, only use it ONCE at the start and keep working with that string instead fo stringifying something that is already a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you keep calling `JSON.stringify()`.

Stringify the json object once and then use str.replace() instead:

```
var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
jsonStr = jsonStr.replace("total_exec_qty_buy", "total_exec_qty");    
jsonStr = jsonStr.replace("total_exec_qty_sell", "total_exec_qty"); 
jsonStr = jsonStr.replace("total_num_ords_buy", "total_num_ords"); 
jsonStr = jsonStr.replace("total_num_ords_sell", "total_num_ords");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are chaining it incorrectly. You are stringifying the string second time onwards.

Try this

```
var stringifiedArr = JSON.stringify(newArray);
stringifiedArr =  stringifiedArr.split('"total_exec_qty_buy":').join('"total_exec_qty":').split('"total_exec_qty_sell":').join('"total_exec_qty":').split('"total_num_ords_buy":').join('"total_num_ords":').split('"total_num_ords_sell":').join('"total_num_ords":');

newArray = JSON.parse( stringifiedArr );
```

You can now optimize this by doing some refactoring

```
function splitAndJoin( str, splitter, joiner )
{
  return str.split( splitter ).join( joiner );
}
var stringifiedArr = JSON.stringify(newArray);
stringifiedArr = splitAndJoin( stringifiedArr , "total_exec_qty_buy", "total_exec_qty" );
```

This looks readable now.